# Почему происходит ошибка "kinetic Release 404 Not Found"?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ppa

При установке панели `ISP6` получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease [118 kB]
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease [99.9 kB]
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Потому что вы надобавляли каких-то левых репозиториев, которые не существуют. Как исправить — ну удалить их, например?

Comment: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ потому что твоего дистра там нет?